# How to return last prime number from interval with while loop and ifs in C#

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, while-loop, primes

I'm trying to display last prime number for a given interval. For example:

1. if n is 10 last prime nubmer is 7
2. if n is 11 last prime nubmer is 11
3. if n is 14 last prime number is 13
4. etc...

   ```
    public static uint LastPrimeNumberInInterval(uint n)
    {
        uint result = 0;
        uint i = 2;

        while (i <= n)
        {
            bool b = false;

            while (i <= n / 2)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                {
                    b = true;
                    break;
                }

                i++;
            }

            if (!b)
            {
                result = i;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }
   ```

but I'm stuck on displaying only correct answer when n is prime number. Can someone point out where is my fault?

Comment: As a side note - cycling down from n will be quicker (that way you can stop checking for primes once you find the first)

Comment: You really only need to test against `2` and then the odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different variable in your nested loop and reset it for each number being checked.

```
public static uint LastPrimeNumberInInterval(uint n)
 {
     uint result = 0;
     uint i = 2;

 while (i <= n)
 {
     bool b = false;
     uint j = 2;

     while (j <= n / 2)
     {
         if (n % j == 0)
         {
             b = true;
             break;
         }

         j++;
     }

     if (!b)
     {
         result = i;
     }

     i++;
 }

 return result;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did something, it can be helpful

```
public static uint GetLastPrimeNumber(uint n)
    {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        uint j = 2;
        while (j < n)
        {
            if (n % j == 0)
            {
                n--;
                j = 2;
                continue;
            }

            j++;
        }

        return n;
    }
```